# How to interrupt and stop a running process using external variable

Tags: python

I am very new to python and code in general so please bear with me.

I have a bit of code that runs through and plays a list of files (like it would on an itunes playlist for example.) I need to be able to stop and restart the loop by toggling a button / variable that is sent from touchosc.

The loop will trigger and run through just fine, but I cannot get it to stop without hitting ctrl-c. The issue seems to be that when the loop is running, my program will not update the "loop" variable with the new value, so as to stop the process when it is changed to 0. I have tried and failed using a number of different methods to get it to work. These have included while-looping and threading (way over my head). If anyone can please point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated! Also please excuse my hacky code -- the r, s, sp and sr flags are there mainly for another part of the program that is working, so i can make sure to kill the processes when i record or trigger different playfiles, to avoid overloading the cpu and also avoid feedback if i were to record to and play back from the same file simultaneously. If you have pointers on how to make that better feel free but I really just want to fix the main issue for now.

Here is the code:

```
from OSC import OSCServer,OSCClient, OSCMessage
import sys
from time import sleep
import time
import types
import os
import subprocess

server = OSCServer( ("10.1.1.143", 7002) )#This has to be the IP of the RaspberryPi on the network
client = OSCClient()

r = None
p = None
sr = 0
sp = 0
loop = 0

def playall(path, tags, args, source):
        global sp
        global p
        global sr
        global r
        global loop
        loop = int(args[0])
        if loop == 1:
            print "Play on Loop";
         for x in range(1,10):
            i = ""
            i = str(x)
            print "Loop Duration", loop;
            if sp == 0:
                        if sr == 0:
                            p = subprocess.Popen(['ola_recorder', '-p', i, '-i 0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                            sp = 1

                        else:
                            r.kill()
                            p = subprocess.Popen(['ola_recorder', '-p', i, '-i 0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                            sp = 1
                            sr = 0

            else:
                if sr == 0:
                    p.kill()
                    p = subprocess.Popen(['ola_recorder', '-p', i, '-i 0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                    sp = 1

                else:
                    p.kill()
                    r.kill()
                    p = subprocess.Popen(['ola_recorder', '-p', i, '-i 0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                    sp = 1
                    sr = 0
            time.sleep(5)
            if loop == 0:
                break

server.addMsgHandler("/3/playall", playall)

while True:
    server.handle_request()

server.close()
```

Comment: What does "external variable" mean to you in this context? Is there a reason you *don't* want to use signals? (ctrl+c sends one kind of signal, but you could also use SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 to do other controls, or just rely on SIGSTOP to pause and SIGCONT to continue, which they'll already do out-of-the-box with no code changes needed).

Comment: If by "external variable" you're referring to shell or environment variables, that won't work, since each program gets its own independent copy of those on creation. But it's not clear what you *do* mean by the term.

Comment: hey @CharlesDuffy the variable i'm referring to in my code is "loop" which i am defining in the function with loop = int(args[0]) this value will always be zero or one and is toggled through when i press the button on touch osc which sends the message to the "/3/playall" defined in the message handler. sorry for my bad terminology, hopefully you can understand what im getting at

Comment: essentially, i want the plalist to loop through when the button is on (loop == 1) and to stop when its off (loop == 0)

Comment: re: Signals - the reason is that i dont know about them as im a total n00b. if you can elaborate that would be great, otherwise i will try google that and see if i can make sense of it.

Comment: One approach to solving this would be to set `loop=1` when SIGUSR1 is received, and `loop=0` when SIGUSR2 is received. See the example in https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html setting a handler for SIGALARM -- you can follow that same pattern for different signals.

Comment: I had a look at the example but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me yet, will give it a crack with fresh eyes tomorrow. Thanks Charles

Comment: If the control of your program is most of the time kept by either your `popen` or `time.sleep`, you'll hardly ever listen to any event with `handle_request`. I suggest using `threading` or `multiprocessing` to effectively verify whether the user is causing the event in a second task.

Comment: How does the message to stop the loop come in to your system? And with the OSC library you are using, does the library automatically run your playall function asynchronously, or does it expect to run a request to completion before anything else happens? My guess would be that the library would give you the facilities you need for this, without having to do your own multithreading or handling signals from the OS or anything like that. What OSC library are you using?

Comment: Thanks very much @Win ! That was the key to the solution, I'm using the pyosc library which indeed includes a threading handler, so I just switched to using a threaded osc server and everything now works as it should :) I'll post the code shortly incase anyone comes across the same issue